# Is MySQL's ON CASCADE DELETE feature supported on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, pdo, google-cloud-sql

Is MySQL's ON CASCADE DELETE feature supported on Google Cloud SQL? I have searched this on Google and Google's support on Cloud SQL, but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You can try this by yourself, but, basically, according [to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features):

- You can create either a first or second generation instance. First Gen supports MySQL 5.5 and 5.6, and Second Gen supports MySQL 5.6 or 5.7
- All of these MySQL versions already supported [this operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
- While there are some limitations to both generations of Cloud SQL instances, they DO support this feature.